# Ordenar listas tipo liveData kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-room

Estoy implementando un proyecto ejemplo de aprendizaje, en el mismo lo que requiero es consultar, actualizar, insertar y eliminar "Notas".

Las notas se muestran en un RecyclerView.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que requiero hacer es cambiar el orden por prioridad de las notas al presionar un botón (menuitem) de manera ascendente o descendente si lo volviese a presionar.

La cuestión es que en mi activity tengo un observador de esta manera en el método onCreate():

```
notaViewModel.consultarNotas()?.observe(this, object : Observer<MutableList<Nota>> {
        override fun onChanged(t: MutableList<Nota>?) {

            adapter.submitList(t!!)
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "onChangedDESC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    })
```

Todo lo anterior funciona perfecto cuando se inserta, modifica o elimina...

Pero para cambiar el orden de aparición tengo que hacer esto que me parece incorrecto:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.deleteAllNotas -> {
            notaViewModel.eliminarNotas()
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Notas eliminadas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return true
        }
        R.id.ordenarAsc ->{
            notaViewModel.consultarNotasAsc()?.observe(this, object : Observer<MutableList<Nota>> {
                override fun onChanged(t: MutableList<Nota>?) {

                    adapter.submitList(t!!)
                    Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "onChangedDESC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            })
            true
        }

        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

Me parece incorrecto porque estoy declarando otro observer y ejecutando otra consulta para que me devuelva los mismos datos pero en orden distinto. Por lo que pierdo el anterior observer.

Con el código implementado si quisiera regresarme al primer orden (descendente) tendría que volver a declarar otro observer?

Saludos y gracias por sus comentarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hice una copia de la lista, al parecer es por esa razón que el adapter no actualiza, además para ordenar los datos sin tener que ir hasta la base de datos hice un sort(), importante la copia la hice con .toMutableList()
aquí el código:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.deleteAllNotas -> {
            notaViewModel.eliminarNotas()
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Notas eliminadas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return true
        }

        R.id.ordenarASC -> {
            val list: MutableList<Nota>? = notaViewModel.consultarNotas()!!.value!!.toMutableList()

            isAsc = !isAsc

            if (isAsc)
                list!!.sort()
            else list!!.reverse()


            adapter.submitList(list)
            true
        }

        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```